# What parameters are showing undefined in this dnvm.ps1 command? Deployment to Azure Web Site Fails as a result

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service, dnx, dnvm

I have been developing a new ASP.NET 5 (MVC 6) website on Linux.

I am using Git with Azure and have been able to successfully push it to SCM.  However my deployment fails due to some undefined parameters.

Hoping someone can tell me what the undefined parameters are in the command shown in the terminal output so I can modify the script and finish this process.

I run the command

```
# git push azure master
```

The following is the output, auto deployment should happen after a successful commit.

[image]

The commit works but when it tries to run the following command it fails.

```
dnvm.ps1' " install undefined -arch undefined -r undefined
```

I believe this is in the Deploy.cmd file generated by

```
#  azure site deploymentscript mysite --aspNet5 project.json
```

that is triggered after a successful commit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you generate your `deploy.cmd` you need to pass in the version, arch, and CLR or CoreCLR

```
azure site deploymentscript mysite --aspNet5 project.json --aspNet5Version <version> --aspNet5Runtime <CLR|CoreCLR> --aspNet5Architecture <x64|x86>
```

so for example for `1.0.0-rc1-final` running on a 32 bit `CoreCLR` you'll need

```
azure site deploymentscript mysite --aspNet5 project.json --aspNet5Version 1.0.0-rc1-final --aspNet5Runtime CoreCLR --aspNet5Architecture x86
```

It's a bug that the generator allows that to happen in the first place. I haven't had the time to fix it, but feel free to open an issue https://github.com/projectkudu/KuduScript/issues but as I understand things are going to change with RC2 so I was waiting for that.

Also keep in mind that azure should auto generate the right `deploy.cmd` if you don't have it there. You really only need to generate it yourself if there is some special logic that you need there that won't be a part of the auto generated one.